# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyTelegramBotAPI' Python

Tags: python, centos, telebot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
(telebot)[root@telebot]# python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) 
[GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pyTelegramBotAPI
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyTelegramBotAPI'

(telebot) [root@telebot]# pip list
Package          Version
---------------- ---------
certifi          2020.6.20
chardet          3.0.4
idna             2.10
pip              20.2.4
pyTelegramBotAPI 3.7.3
requests         2.24.0
setuptools       39.2.0
six              1.15.0
urllib3          1.25.11
```

CentOS8, дистрибутив чистый, только поставил. Делал по этому гайду, только ставил версию питона 3.6 https://avalon.land/blog/it/telegram-bot-on-centos7/

Comment: потому что импортировать надо `import telebot`

Answer (score 0):

Собственно покопавшись еще, нашел ответ. Надо было писать

```
import telebot
```

А не так как у него в гайде, вопрос решен.